# Get graph of the weekly season for a time series with daily frequency

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

How can I decompose a time series of daily frequency in R?  I have the number of visitors to a website each day over the course of a year.  I want to show a graph of the weekly season.

```
my_data = read.csv("time series test.csv", header = TRUE)

my_zoo_ts = read.zoo("time series test.csv", sep = ",", format="%m/%d/%y")

stl(my_zoo_ts)
# Error in stl(coerced_ts) : 
#   series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

I was hoping to use STL, but apparently STL can't be used with daily data (from another S.O. question).

Here is the head of my data.

```
head(my_data)
      V1  V2
1 1/1/14 123
2 1/2/14 128
3 1/3/14 129
4 1/4/14 130
5 1/5/14 137
6 1/6/14 141
```

Comment: It can be used for daily data. But with more than two years of data. Anyway, what do you want to decompose?

Comment: `stl` cannot be used with `"Date"` class data.  The data must be regularly spaced and one period must have the duration of 1.

Comment: @Pascal - I want to decompose a time series where it's the number of unique visitors to a website each day over 1 year. The periods would be weeks (since people visit certain websites more on certain days of the week). Is there any other function I can use?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - thanks I can create a series with `zoo`that is just a single vector regularly spaced. But I can't figure out how to specify the period to be 1 week.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to aggregate daily to weekly data?

Comment: @DannyP,  Objects of `"Date"` class are internally days since the Epoch so successive days are one unit apart; thus, to have a week represent one unit divide by 7: `library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(my_data, format = "%m/%d/%y"); time(z) <- as.numeric(time(z))/7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z <- as.Date("2014-1-1") + 0:364
visits <- sample(seq(from = 50, to = 100, by = 1), size = 365, replace = TRUE)
z.day <- zoo(visits, z)
week <- as.numeric(format(time(z.day), "%W"))
z.week <- aggregate(z.day, week, sum)
```

Then plot z.week

Answer (score 0):

You should either aggregate the week or aggregate over the day-of-the-week.

Then you can plot the aggregates.

If you need further details, can you explain what you want to see?